# What is the proper way of creating bullet in libgdx ashley ecs framework?

Tags: java, libgdx, entity-system, entity-component, entity

I'm still thinking, how do I properly pool a bullet in libgdx ashley? Because the `PooledEngine` is available, which the `Entities`, `Components` and `Systems` are already `Pooled`. I made this below example, which I just create a [builder-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to spawn a bullet. Without using the ashley ECS framework, I used this [memory-management](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management) reference to create a bullet pool as result this made me more confused.

```
class EntityFactory {

     ...

     public EntityFactory(World world, PooledEngine engine) {

          this.engine = engine;
          this.world = world;

     }

     public Entity createBullet(float x, float y) {
          ...
     }

}

class GunSystem extends IteratingSystem {

     EntityFactory factory;

     public GunSystem(EntityFactory factory) {
          super(Mappers.gunFamily);
          this.factory = factory;
     }

     @Override
     public void processEntity(Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
          GunComponent gun = Mappers.gun.get(entity);
          NodeComponent node = Mappers.node.get(entity);              

          float bulletX = ...;
          float bulletY = ...;

          if(gun.reload) {
               Entity bullet = factory.createBullet(bulletX, bulletY);
               node.putChild("bullet", bullet);
          }


          if(gun.fire) {
               Entity bullet = node.getChild("bullet");
               ... move body to target destination
               BulletComponent b
               b.state.fired = true;
               node.removeChild("bullet");
          }

     }

}
```

**Question** what do you think is the proper way of creating bullet pool in ashley ecs framework?